# security util using SecurityContextHolder in spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

in my spring application I have some aspects for controller methods where I do some security checks. beacause of I need several checks more often I wrapped them into static helper methods of a "sercurityUtil" class.:

```
public abstract class SecurityUtils {

    public static Authentication getCurrentAuthentication(){
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }

    public static ChroniosUser getAuthenticatedUser(){
        return (ChroniosUser) getCurrentAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }

    public static boolean authenticationHasRole(Authentication authentication, Role role){
        SimpleGrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleIdentifier());
        return authentication.getAuthorities().contains(grantedAuthority);
    }

    public static boolean authenticatedUserIsAdmin(){
        Authentication authentication = getCurrentAuthentication();
        return authenticationHasRole(authentication, ADMIN);
    }

    ...
}
```

is this a valid and good approach?
or shut I wrap these helper functions into a spring service?

thank you.

PS: I know that I can use @PreAuthorize ... but my aspects are more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is :

**Yes** it seems to be a valid and good approach.

The long answer is :

It's up to you.

Spring Security documentation states that its infrastructure is based entirely on standard servlet filters and has no strong links to any particuler web technology, including Spring MVC

> Spring Security’s web infrastructure is based entirely on standard
>   servlet filters. It doesn’t use servlets or any other servlet-based
>   frameworks (such as Spring MVC) internally, so it has no strong links
>   to any particular web technology. It deals in `HttpServletRequest` s and
>   `HttpServletResponse` s and doesn’t care whether the requests come from
>   a browser, a web service client, an `HttpInvoker` or an AJAX application

[[Spring Security Reference - 1. The Security Filter Chain]](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#security-filter-chain)

Its use is based nearly entirely on the [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#securitycontextholder-securitycontext-and-authentication-objects). The examples provided are through static methods :

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

As you can see, it's not a Spring Bean/Service/Component. `SecurityContextHolder` itself looks like a utility class.

Now you can create a Spring Service to expose it or you can use it through a classic [*Util* class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_class) depending on what is more practical to you and for your application.